# Caixeiro Viajante - Algoritmo Exaustivo

Tags: python-3.x, algoritmo, grafo

Preciso criar um algoritmo que:
 1. Descubra todos os possíveis caminhos que visitem todos os vértices de um grafo sem passar pelo mesmo vértices duas vezes.
 2. Armazene todos os resultados.
 3. Retorne o caminho com a menor distância.

Resumindo, uma solução exaustiva/bruta para o Problema do Caixeiro Viajante.
Não sei nem como fazer um algoritmo que descubra todas as possibilidades, pensei em fazer um que teste tudo aleatoriamente e armazene apenas os caminhos diferentes dos já armazenados, mas assim ainda ficaria sem saber quando parar(já que nunca terei a garantia de que todas as possibilidades foram realmente testadas).

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a melhor por causa disto. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português (versão curta)](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045). Se a ajuda for muito simples ainda é possível fazer nos comentários.

Comment: Você poderia passar mais detalhes? Neste caso, tem o número de estradas, a quilometragem delas? Se puder editar a pergunta e inserir as informações, ajudaria bastante.

Comment: Recomendo verificar este link https://towardsdatascience.com/solving-travelling-salesperson-problems-with-python-5de7e883d847