# Como descobrir todos os possíveis caminhos para visitar todos os vértices de um grafo?

Tags: python, algoritmo, grafo

Preciso armazenar todas as possíveis rotas para visitar os vértices de um grafo sem passar por um mesmo vértice duas vezes (TSP), pensei em gerar as rotas aleatoriamente e armazenar todas que não forem repetidas. 
Problema com essa solução: eu não saberia quando já tiver encontrado todas as rotas, não sabendo assim quando mandar o programa parar.
Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Essa não é exatamente a pergunta que fez em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/426502/5878? Qual é a diferença?

Comment: a cada bifurcação no grafo é uma lista que simboliza um caminho, para não repetir um vertice basta verificar se ele ja esta na lista

Comment: @Woss A pergunta anterio foi fechada por estar muito abrangente. Decidi por fazer uma pergunta mais especifica desta vez.

Comment: @EltonNunes Um amigo me disse a mesma coisa, mas não entendi exatamente como isso funciona. Você poderia explicar em mais detalhes ou mostrar um exemplo?

Comment: Acredito que ainda ainda está bastante ampla. Você consegue [edit] e adicionar o seu código dos grafos, dar um exemplo de poucos vértices e descrever qual seria o resultado esperado para o exemplo?

Comment: sim, vou aprontar aqui e posto quando tiver uma exemplo

Answer (score 2):

tendo o grafo definido na imagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ele não tem qualquer restrição, optei por usar um dicionario(vertice:saidas) para representá-lo

```
grafo = { 
    '1' : '234',
    '2' : '134',
    '3' : '124',
    '4' : '123',
    }
```

achei o uso de recursão mais facil para solucionar

```
def acharCaminhos(caminho, meta, grafo):
```

**caminho** seria uma string marcando o vertice A

**meta** é o vertice B

**grafo** é grafo

```
    if len(caminho) != len(set(caminho)): return
```

usando **len** e **set** consigo saber se tem *vertices repetidos* no caminho

```
    if caminho[-1] == meta:
        print(caminho)
        return
```

verifico se o ultimo vertice no caminho é a meta

```
    for i in grafo[caminho[-1]]:
        acharCaminhos(caminho+i, meta, grafo)
```

este loop garente a recursividade para todas as bifurcações